# Basic redirecting to a modern server, while keeping the domain name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Apologies if this has been beaten to death, but all I've been able to find are overly technical articles.

**My question is simple:**

A friend at the university wants to start a website. He wants to use a university domain name (http://university.com/my-awesome-website). The problem is that I want to build it with WordPress, but the university is still using PHP4, so WP isn't possible!!

Can I setup a `.htaccess` file or similar so that when someone goes to http://university.com/my-awesome-website, the urls look right, but the pages are actually coming from WordPress on a different server?

Is this what they call 'domain masking' or is it a '301' redirect?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [IFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to load the wordpress site in and make it look like it's being served up on the same site.

Comment: Wow. Never thought of that!  Any foreseeable downside to doing this?  I guess the URLs would all look the same?  I wouldn't be able to tell people to go to http://university.com/my-website/contact, for example?